# How to set placeholder for mat-radio-button or mat-radio-group?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have a DOM element:

```
<mat-radio-group [formControlName]="field.name" [disabled]="field?.disabled">
  <div>
    <mat-label>{{ placeholder }}</mat-label>
  </div>
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option.value">
    {{ option.label }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

How to set native placeholder for `mat-radio-button` or `mat-radio-group` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <label [attr.for]="aaa">PlaceHolder</label>
    </legend>
    <div class="row">
        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
            <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

How it look:

[image]